# How to find the type of excel file in angular 2? Either it is macro or not

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the type of excel file either it is macro or not.

I used XLXS library but do not get the result.

```
wb_has_macro(wb/*:selectedfile*/)/*:boolean*/ {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      const arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
      const data = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      const arr = new Array();
      for (let i = 0; i !== data.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
      }
      const bstr = arr.join('');
      this.workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
      const first_sheet_name = this.workbook.SheetNames[0];
      const worksheet = this.workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
      if (!!this.workbook.vbaraw) {
        return true;
      }
    const sheets = this.workbook.SheetNames.map((n) => 
    this.workbook.Sheets[n]);
    return sheets.some((ws) => {
    return !!ws && ws['!type'] === 'chart';
  });
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(wb._file);}
```

Comment: Add the code snippet of what you have already tried (the use of XLXS library that you mention)

Comment: excel files are zip files

Comment: @FranciscoHanna i added the code snippet